# How to use shared_pointer as value in a std::map structure?

Tags: c++, memory-management, protocol-buffers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a map structure as below which has shared_pointer of a protobuf structure Stats:

```
map<string, shared_pointer<vol::proto::Stats> statsMap;
```

I am storing and retrieving the map entries through a LRU cache implementation

```
template class LRUCache<string,std::shared_ptr<vol::proto::Stats>>;
```

### Protobuf structure:-

```
message Stats {
    required string oid = 1;
    required int64  logical_size = 2;   
    required int64  committed_size = 3; 
}
message StatsRequest {
    required string uuid = 1;
}
```

### The function for storing entry into the map:-

```
template<class K, class V>
void
LRUCache<K, V>::Put(const K& key, V value)
{
    Vmacore::System::WriteSynchronized lock(this);
    auto val = refMap.find(key);
    if (val == refMap.end()) {
        if (cacheSize == refMap.size()) {
            K leastUsedKey = lruList.back();
            lruList.pop_back();
            refMap.erase(leastUsedKey);
        }
    } else {
        lruList.erase(val->second.lruKeyRef);
    }
    lruList.push_front(key);
    refMap[key] = LRUValueReference<K, V>(lruList.begin(), value);
}

void PutS(const string& Id, const vol::proto::Stats& info)
{  
    shared_ptr<vol::proto::Stats> statsInfo = make_shared<vol::proto::Stats>(info);
    _StatsCache.Put(Id, statsInfo);
}

void PutStats(vol::proto::StatsRequest &req) {
    vol::proto::Stats *stats;
    GetStats(stats); //stats gets populated here.
    PutS(stats->oid(), *stats);
}
```

### To Get the entry from the map:-

```
template<class K, class V>
bool
LRUCache<K, V>::Get(const K& key, V& value)
{
    Vmacore::System::WriteSynchronized lock(this);
    auto val = refMap.find(key);
    if (val == refMap.end()) {
        return false;
    }
    lruList.splice(lruList.begin(), lruList, val->second.lruKeyRef);
    val->second.lruKeyRef = lruList.begin();
    value = val->second.value;
    return true;
}
void GetS(const string& Id, shared_ptr<vol::proto::Stats> info)
{  
    if (!_StatsCache.Get(Id, info))
        return false;
    return true;
}
void GetStats(vol::proto::StatsRequest &req) {
    shared_ptr<vol::proto::Stats> stats;
    if (GetS(req.uuid(), stats)) {
        Log("object id is %s", stats.get()->oid()); // Crash at oid (this=0x0)
    }
}
```

Now while doing GetStats, I am seeing a crash as to in GetStats's Log statement that is program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  Should I do a make_share for Stats in GetStats? Can you please describe as to what has caused this crash and how to fix the crash here?

Comment: Did you use a debugger to investigate your program?  Likely somebody is either inserting an empty `shared_ptr` or it's not the `shared_ptr` that's cause your segfault.

Comment: You should find which line of code crashed using debugger and/or coredump.

Comment: Log("object id is %s", stats.get()->oid()); // Crash at oid (this=0x0) in GetStats() is causing crash

Comment: Does this code compile? I suspect it doesn't

Comment: Yes. I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a raw pointer from `GetStats` to `GetS`, which then wraps it into a `shared_ptr`. Now lets start ref-counting.

- GetS -> increase on entry > 1
- _StatsCache.Get -> pass by ref > 1
- GetS -> decrease on exit > 0
- Ref count 0 -> delete the pointer.

In `GetStats` you then try to de-reference the `stats` pointer by calling `.get`, but it was just deleted.

You should either **always** use smart pointers, or be very very very careful when you convert from raw pointer to smart pointer, and back.

---

Actually what I wrote is wrong. What you're doing is actually much worse.

You're wrapping a raw pointer in `GetS` into a smart pointer, and then pass it by ref to your `_StatsCache.Get`, which then assigns a different `shared_ptr` to yours. So you've overwritten the original raw pointer with something else.

But when `GetS` returns, that `shared_ptr` is now lost and destructed, but the original `stats` pointer is accessed in `stats.get()`. What's in it? Nothing from `GetS`, that's for sure.

Comment: Sorry Actually passing shared_ptr to GetS. Some copy-paste error. Now edited GetStats() code again.

Comment: You're passing it by value, `value = val->second.value` does nothing to it.